# Report Builder 3.0 can't deploy reports to SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, sql-server-2014-express

I deployed a report to a SQL Server 2014 report server which worked. Then I tried to deploy the same report to an SQL Server2014 Express report server but it didn't work. It gave me this error message:

> The feature "Report part gallery" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.

I tried googling it and this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365156(v=sql.105).aspx#WebAPI) clearly says that report part gallery is not part of SQL Server 2008 R2. I haven't found any comparison on any newer version of SQL Server.

When googling "report part gallery" I find that report part gallery is a feature in Report Builder 3.0 that allows a user to create and use reports and reuse them in other reports. Link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ee636148.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

But still my question is unanswered. Can I deploy reports with Report Builder 3.0 to SQL Server 2014 Express report server? If so, please help. If not please give me some documentation of it.

If Report Builder 3.0 can't deploy reports to SQL Server 2014 Express report server, are there any alternatives to a standard or higher edition of SQL Server 2014 report server (not express)?

Answer (score 0):

Don´t use "deploy" in Report Builder, save .rdl file. 
Use web interface to upload .rdl file to ReportServer. 
(URL to Report Manager:  http://localhost/reports_SQLExpress2014)